# What is happening in this example middleware: if request.path = "/i.auth"

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-middleware

I am looking at a pretty outdated tutorial [here](http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/create-invite-only-website.html). My question though, only relates to a snippet of this code, particularly this snippet:

```
class InviteMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, req):
        if req.path == '/i.auth'
            return None
        if not req.user.is_authenticated():
            if 'token' in req.COOKIES:
                return redirect(reverse('invite_reg_user'))
        return None
```

specifically this line:

```
if req.path == '/i.auth'
```

What is the path /i.auth? How is this being used and why did the author of this article check the path using this? I have searched the internet and it seems like i.auth doesn't necessarily pertain to anything. What is the author really trying to check?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the author took the middleware from an existing project that uses `/i.auth` for some view and that this middleware should be bypassed when that view is requested. He simply forgot to remove this bit of code when he published the article.